# Python - decimal places (putting floats into a string)

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I have been using the format:

```
print 'blah, blah %f' %variable
```

to put variables into strings. I heard it was more pythonic than the '+str()+' approach, and have got quite used to it. 
Is there a way of specifying the decimal places added to the string with %f? I have tried rounding the number before supplying the variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> variable = 12
>>> print 'blah, blah %4.3f' %variable
blah, blah 12.000
>>> print 'blah, blah %1.1f' %variable
blah, blah 12.0
```

Here is the [Python Doc Link](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting), please consider:

> Since str.format() is quite new, a lot of Python code still uses the %
>   operator. However, because this old style of formatting will
>   eventually be removed from the language, str.format() should generally
>   be used.

Comment: The switch from `%` to `str.format` is something I've never understood. Both work fine, but the printf-style one is something people will already be familiar with, and it is distinctly faster, and it uses less code. I continue to use `%` most of the time for myself, and as it's still around in Python 3.2 I think I'll continue to do it even when using Python 3 for lots of things.

Comment: hope they do keep it in, it's definitely quicker to code and less annoying!

Comment: @Chris Morgan, see [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/). One of the things I like a lot about `str.format` is that it's so easy to switch between positional and named arguments without having to re-write the template.

Comment: @Kirk: I have read it before but it didn't help me to see why they would recommend not using `%`, or why it would eventually be removed.

Comment: @Chris: Well, the biggest reason is that `%` only accepts one argument, so you have to choose wisely. If you pick wrong (say you were passing in a tuple of positional values and want to add a keyword value), you have to re-write the whole thing. With `format`, you can pass in any combination of arguments that any other function would accept. I'm sure someone will also come up with a use case where having `format` as a first-class function is handy.

Comment: @Kirk: but `%` is so much easier/shorter to use!  (And it's ugly in what I think is the most common usage of `%`, just joining multiple parts where all quantities are known.)

Comment: @Chris: Don't get me wrong: I use `%` all the time. You'll find it a lot more often than `format` in my own code. Still, I can see a few advantages in `format` and I'll probably start working it into my projects more often.

Comment: What does the `4` do in `print 'blah, blah %4.3f' %variable` do?

Answer (score 6):

In Python version 2.6 and newer, you can use:

```
>>> print('blah, blah {0:.2f}'.format(variable))
```

where "0" refers to the first value passed into str.format, ":" says "here comes the format specification", and ".2f" means "floating point number with two decimal places of precision". This is the suggested way of formatting strings now.

Answer (score 2):

For Python version 3.6 and upwards there is also the option to use f-strings, which works in a quite similar fashion to what Kirk Strauser showed in his answer

```
print(f'blah, blah {variable:.2f}')
```

Comment: The _only_ reason I use my answer these days is when I need to define a template somewhere then fill it in later. I use f-strings for pretty much everything else. They're lovely!

Comment: Yeah it's the same for me. That's why I figured f-strings would be useful to add to this question